# Sequences not in $l^p$

Tags: real-analysis

I am wondering if there is an easy sequence $x_n \in \mathbb R$ with $x_n \to 0$ and $x_n \notin l^p$ for all $1 \le p < \infty$.

I found $x_n = (\log n)^{-1}$ satisfies $x_n \to 0$ and $x_n \notin l^p$ because

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty |x_n|^p \ge \sum_{n=2}^\infty |x_{n+1}|^p \ge \int_2^\infty (\log x)^{-p} dx \ge \int_2^\infty (\log x)^{-1} dx = (x(\log x -1))_2^\infty = \infty$.

But it is complicated. Is there an easier example?

Comment: I found one: $x_n = n^{1/n}$. But the proof I wrote in the question for the other sequence is incorrect.

Comment: $x_n=n^{1/n}$ does not satisfy $x_n\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: $n^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$, not zero. (Take log, apply L'Hospital's rule.)

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you. I will have to search further for better example.

Comment: Use the [Cauchy Condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) for your first sequence.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you for help. I was hoping to find easier example without a logarithm.

Comment: For each integer $m$, select $m_n$ so that $(\underbrace{1/m,1/m,\ldots,1/m}_{m_n-\text{terms}})$ has $\ell_m$ norm exceeding $1$. Then paste these sequences together. (I don't think this is any easier than using your sequence.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your example is good.

A Bertrand series
$$
\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n^\alpha(\ln n)^\beta}
$$
converges if and only if $\alpha>1$, or $\alpha=1$ and $\beta>1$.

In your case $\alpha=0$ so it always diverges.

**Proof** in the case $\alpha =0$ and $\beta>0$ (your case).:

Since the general term is nonnegative and nonincreasing, the series is of the same nature as the the integral
$$
\int_2^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln x)^\beta}dx.
$$
Now observe that 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{(\ln x)^\beta}=+\infty.
$$
So eventually, for $x\geq M\geq $, say,
$$
\frac{1}{(\ln x)^\beta}\geq  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
hence 
$$
\int_2^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln x)^\beta}dx\geq \int_M^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln x)^\beta}dx \geq \int_M^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx=+\infty.
$$

Comment: Is there not easier example? Without logarithm?

Comment: That's a very natural example you found. I can't think of an easier example right now, and I doubt you can find one. Simpler, for example, would be Riemann $p$-series, but they don't help here. Note that it depends alos on what you call easier. Bertrand series are not that difficlt, after all.